# Реализация autocomplete с помощью jquery

Tags: javascript, java, servlet

Привет народ, есть вопрос, есть вот такой вот скрипт

```
$( function() {

    var availableTags = [
      "ИК6","ИК61","ИК62","ИК63","ИК64","ИК65",
      "ТРК"
    ];
    $( "#kiz" ).autocomplete({
      source: availableTags
    });
  } );
```

проблема в том что все данные в массив нужно добавлять в ручную, можно ли как-то в сервлете сделать запрос по полю `kiz` и передать потом сформированный массив в скрипт в переменную `availableTags`

Comment: Поясните момент: Вручную данные добавляются на сервере? Или добавляются на клиенте и отправляются на сервер?

Comment: `var availableTags = [
      "ИК6","ИК61","ИК62","ИК63","ИК64","ИК65",
      "ТРК"
    ];` вот эти данные что в массиве `availableTags`, я ввожу вручную в скрипте, а хотелось что бы их можно было как-то с базы данных брать

Comment: То есть при рендинге страницы Вам нужно что бы ваши значения подставлялись в массив так?

Comment: эти значения что сейчас в массиве показываются в инпуте на странице, мне же нужно что бы значения брались с базы данных, ибо в ручную вводить тысячи имен явно не то что нужно.

Comment: Ну так, просто сформируйте массив на стороне сервера и подставьте в шаблон HTML страницы. Хотя это не очень хорошая реализация. Хранить "тысячи" имен на странице пользователя, будет очень больно для браузера. Рискну предположить что вы используете `autocomplete` из jq ui. В примерах к нему есть [реализация](https://jqueryui.com/autocomplete/#remote) подгруздки данных из удаленного источника. То есть вам необходимо создать на сервере отдельный хендлер который по запросу от jq будет отдавать JSON с подходящими результатами.

Comment: да именно из jq ui, если бы я знал как это сделать с json не работал, спасибо за совет

Comment: К сожалению с servlet помочь не могу, однако вот [видео](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=AslUnopO1Rg) с простой инструкцией, правда на английском.

Comment: видео не помогло, а вот Ваш ответ выше, очень даже)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Сделал, может кому поможет, в сервлете я вызываю метод из дао класса, где идет запрос в БД. И нужно подключить библиотеку Gson, для преобразования полученных данных из БД в json формат

```
                String term = request.getParameter("term");

                System.out.println("Data from ajax call " + term);
                                /*Список кизов*/
                Vp44150sqlDao vp44150sqlDao = new Vp44150sqlDao();
                ArrayList<String> list = vp44150sqlDao.getFrameWork(term);

                String searchList = new Gson().toJson(list);
                response.getWriter().write(searchList);
```

А скрипт выглядит так

```
$(document).ready(function() {
     $(function() {

         $("#kiz").autocomplete({     
             source : function(request, response) {
                 //$("#loading").show();
                 $(".ui-helper-hidden-accessible").empty();

               $.ajax({
                    url : "AutocompleteKizController",
                    type : "GET",
                    data : {
                           term : request.term
                    },
                    dataType : "json",
                    success : function(data) {
                          response(data);
                       //   $("#loading").hide();
                    }
             });
          }

      });
   });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$("#tags").autocomplete({
  source: "search.php", // url-адрес
  minLength: 2 // минимальное количество для совершения запроса
});
```

а это сервер

```
$elements = findAutocomplete($_GET['term']);
$s = "[".implode(",", $elements)."]";
echo $s;
```

понятно?

Comment: ну я так понимаю сервер это php? я просто пишу на java, ну и сама структура того что на сервере не очень понятна(

Comment: ессно php, или по вашему желанию что хотите, главное json получать